# Casting from a ListModel into a DefaultListModel in Java 7

Tags: java

How can I cast a ListModel to a DefaultListModel??!  I perform  the following and I get this error message,

```
DefaultListModel portalListModel = (DefaultListModel) portalList.getModel();

C:\Documents and Settings\...\myfile.java:728: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: DefaultListModel
    DefaultListModel portalListModel = (DefaultListModel) portalList.getModel();
missing type arguments for generic class DefaultListModel<E>
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class DefaultListModel
```

I tried the following,

```
DefaultListModel<E> portalListModel = (DefaultListModel) portalList.getModel();
```

I have a feeling tha this is a stupid question but I'm totally confued with this new generic thing!  Please help me out!

Comment: What type of data (which class) is in your list model?

Comment: If you do not know the exact type argument, you can use the `?`. Try `DefaultListModel<?> portalListModel = (DefaultListModel) portalList.getModel();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that Java's Collections work is that you can use Collection-type objects to store a whole bunch of Objects.  Prior to the introduction of Generics, you could store any object in a Collection, and then you had to perform a cast when you wanted to get those Objects out of your collection.

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("string");
myList.add(new MyValueClass(42, "identifying string"));
```

That's perfectly acceptable code.  If you wanted to iterate over the objects, you could do it like so:

```
Iterator it = myList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String str = (String) it.next();  // NOTE: This will work the first time, but throw a ClassCastException when it gets to the second item.
}
```

With Java 1.5, Generics provides compile-time type checking upon insertion into the list.  So now, if you declare `myList` as a `List<String>`, the first block of code above will fail at compile time when you attempt to add an object of type `MyValueClass` to the List.

In Java 1.7, `DefaultListModel` is genericized.  So when you call `portalList.getModel()`, you're going to get back a `DefaultListModel` that contains a certain type of object (which is what the `<E>` is; it's a placeholder for the actual object type.)  In the above `List<String>` example, `String` is the substitution for `E`.

So if your `portalList` object's `model` member is a `DefaultListModel` that contains a bunch of `MyValueClass` objects, then your declaration should look like:

```
DefaultListModel<MyValueClass> portalListModel = portalList.getModel();
```

See the [DefaultListModel API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html).

Comment: Could someone please explain the //NOTE: in his answer?

Comment: Sure.  So in my example (the first code block), we have a basic (pre-Java-1.5-style) `List` object called `myList` that contains two objects.  The first object in `myList` is of class `String`.  The second object in `myList` is of class `MyValueClass`.  Thus, when you iterate over the values in `myList` to pull them out, the code inside the iterator is specifically expecting `String` objects.  The first time through the loop, it'll work fine.  The second time, however, it will grab the `MyValueClass` object, try to cast it to `String`, and throw a `ClassCastException`.